# Why can't I use from the static method of the implemented interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, java-8, static-methods

As you, specialists, know in Java 8, interfaces can have static methods which have implementations inside themselves.

As I have read in a related tutorial, the classes which implement such interface can use its static methods. But, I have a problem which, here, I show it in a simpler example than what I have

```
public interface Interface1{
    public static void printName(){
        System.out.println("Interface1");
    }
}
```

when I implement such interface

```
public class Class1 implements Interface1{
    public void doSomeThing() {
        printName();
    }
}
```

I encounter compile error.

```
The method printName() is undefined for the type Class1
```

What's the problem?

Comment: In your example you are trying to call method printName();. The compilation error you are getting is because there is no method in your class "Class1" named as printName(); and compiler is trying to find that method in your class only.

Comment: *"As I have read in a related tutorial, the classes which implement such interface can use its static methods."* They can, yes -- as can classes that *don't* implement the interface. In both cases, you have to qualify the call (`Interface1.printName();`). If the tutorial suggested the above should work, though, it's simply wrong.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[From the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8),

> A class C inherits from its direct superclass all concrete methods m
>   (both static and instance) of the superclass for which all of the
>   following are true:
>
> - [...]
>
> A class C inherits from its direct superclass and direct
>   superinterfaces all abstract and default (§9.4) methods m for which
>   all of the following are true:
>
> - [...]
>
> **A class does not inherit static methods from its superinterfaces.**

So that method is not inherited.

You can statically import the member

```
import static com.example.Interface1.printName;
...
printName();
```

or use it with the fully qualified type name

```
com.example.Interface1.printName();
```

or import the type to which `printName` belongs and invoke it with its short name

```
import static com.example.Interface1;
...
Interface1.printName();
```

Comment: More generally...  this reflects a (deliberate) asymmetry between the treatment of static methods in classes and in interfaces -- static methods in classes are inherited by subtypes, but static methods in interfaces are not.  This was a carefully-considered decision; after all, confusion like the OPs question is the natural result of introducing such asymmetries.  However, the EG strongly felt that existing inheritance of static methods in classes was essentially a design bug, and that extending it to interfaces would create many confusing multiple-inheritance corner cases for little benefit.